# Snowflake (LEFT JOIN) LATERAL: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

> [Lateral Join](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html)
>
> In a FROM clause, the LATERAL keyword allows an in-line view to reference columns from a table expression that precedes that in-line view.
>
> A lateral join behaves more like a correlated subquery than like most JOINs.

Let's tweak the code provided in documentation a bit:

```
CREATE TABLE departments (department_id INTEGER, name VARCHAR);
CREATE TABLE employees (employee_ID INTEGER, last_name VARCHAR,
                        department_ID INTEGER, project_names ARRAY);

INSERT INTO departments (department_ID, name) VALUES 
    (1, 'Engineering'), 
    (2, 'Support'),
    (3, 'HR');  -- adding new row

INSERT INTO employees (employee_ID, last_name, department_ID) VALUES 
    (101, 'Richards', 1),
    (102, 'Paulson',  1),
    (103, 'Johnson',  2);
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM departments AS d,
LATERAL (SELECT * FROM employees AS e 
         WHERE e.department_ID = d.department_ID 
         ORDER BY employee_id DESC LIMIT 1) AS iv2  -- adding ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...
ORDER BY employee_ID;
```

> *SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated*

Yes, I am aware I could rewrite this query with `ROW_NUMBER()` or other ways.

---

1) Why the usage of `TOP/LIMIT` is not possible in this particular scenario?

2) Is there a syntax to achieve `LEFT JOIN LATERAL/OUTER APPLY`?

I would like to be able too get all source rows in the resultset even if the LATERAL subquery produces no rows for them. To get as final result:

```
┌────────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ department_id  │    name      │ employee_id  │ last_name  │ department_id  │ project_names │
├────────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│             1  │ Engineering  │ 102          │ Paulson    │ 1              │ null          │
│             2  │ Support      │ 103          │ Johnson    │ 2              │ null          │
│             3  │ HR           │ null         │ null       │ null           │ null          │
└────────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4ca89eb87c27ea16478798a0ff807240)**

Comment: well the error states the problem, which I find one bumps into a lot, which is correlated sub queries are not supported (in the general form) and sometimes they rewrite stuff into a correlated sub query. So you have to work around it, but doing more/larger simple things in CTEs and the likes and then join together. But as you note you understand how to do this. So thus the not an answers but a, Yes! welcome to snowflake.. I generally say to new to it co-workers, "it's not a DB but a map/reduce pretending to an a DB, so think like it thinks not how a DB thinks"

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim `well the error states the problem, which I find one bumps into a lot, which is correlated sub queries are not supported (in the general form)` -> the whole point of LATERAL is to work with correlated subqueries/functions. Here the issue seems to be the usage of `LIMIT` clause. I am wondering what is the reason and/or there is a list of features that may not be supported. Yes, I could switch paradigm and I will do :) Since it is uisng SQL as access method, I assumed that it is fully compliant.

Comment: I agree LATERAL is a correlated sub-query thing, at a purest form. My learning was via FLATTERN for JSON, but otherwise they are optimizations of joins. They make sense in a context of RDB where you have indexes, but given snowflake is indexless, I tend to think of Snowfalke as parallel filters and merge joins. In that context there is no optimality of a sub-querry. That's just my mental model that helps me get around the gaps in the standard SQL model, which are mostly optimizations that any one system adds to avoid expensive big table scans. Which kind of (to me) the SF model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So even though we have previously discussed that you know you can rewrite it, here is it rewrite

```
WITH departments AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (1, 'Engineering'), 
        (2, 'Support'),
        (3, 'HR')
        v(department_ID, name)
), employees AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (101, 'Richards', 1),
        (102, 'Paulson',  1),
        (103, 'Johnson',  2)
        v(employee_ID, last_name, department_ID)
), dep_emp AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM employees 
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY department_ID ORDER BY employee_id) = 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM departments AS d
LEFT JOIN dep_emp AS e ON d.department_ID = e.department_ID
ORDER BY employee_ID;
```

gives as you wished:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID    NAME           EMPLOYEE_ID    LAST_NAME    DEPARTMENT_ID
1                Engineering    101            Richards     1
2                Support        103            Johnson      2
3                HR             null           null         null
```

By moving from a LATERAL to a CTE with the QUALIFY to implement the LIMIT/TOP and then using a LEFT JOIN to get the empty matches, you have the steps you want.

To the unasked question of why is it this way. Snowflake is not really a per-row Database, it's more a Map/Reduce/MergeJoin processes, and simple correlated subqueries it can rewrite as multi-steps (aka like CTE/joins) but complex stuff it cannot. They are improving it all the time. But given you know your data and you know your model, it just makes most sense to express things in batches of operations and let the power of MergeJoin give you wins.

> Is there a syntax to achieve LEFT JOIN LATERAL/OUTER APPLY?
> this is done via parameter `, OUTER => TRUE` in the [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html#syntax) command