# Snowflake: Unsupported subquery for DISTINCT - Column order matters?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two related tables (unnecessary columns not listed):

`LOCATION`

```
VENUE_ID - NUMBER(38,0)
```

`VISIT`

```
ID - NUMBER(38,0)
VENUE_ID - NUMBER(38,0)
DEVICE_ID - VARCHAR(16777216)
```

The tables are related such that visits are associated with a location via `VENUE_ID`.

I'm attempting to get the count of unique device ids by location, so I wrote the following query:

```sql
SELECT "d"."VENUE_ID"
    , (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT "f0"."DEVICE_ID"
          FROM "MAIN"."VISIT" AS "f0"
          WHERE "d"."VENUE_ID" = "f0"."VENUE_ID"
      ) AS "t")
FROM "MAIN"."LOCATION" AS "d"
```

Unfortunately, this query resulted in the cryptic error `SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`.

Through a bit of experimentation, I've found that I can get the query to return without error, but only if I add an additional (useless) subquery prior to the existing one in the SELECT:

```sql
SELECT "d"."VENUE_ID"

    -- New Useless Subquery
    , (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM "MAIN"."VISIT" AS "f"
      WHERE "d"."VENUE_ID" = "f"."VENUE_ID")
    --

    , (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT "f0"."DEVICE_ID"
          FROM "MAIN"."VISIT" AS "f0"
          WHERE "d"."VENUE_ID" = "f0"."VENUE_ID"
      ) AS "t")
FROM "MAIN"."LOCATION" AS "d"
```

If I move the new subquery to anywhere in the select *after* the distinct subquery, the error returns. I've reviewed [the documentation on subqueries in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html) and either I am not understanding how that applies to my query here or I'm facing undocumented behavior. Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: You could avoid correlated subqeury  by using LEFT JOIN `SELECT "d"."VENUE_ID", COUNT(DISTINCT "f0"."DEVICE_ID")
FROM "MAIN"."LOCATION" AS "d"
LEFT JOIN "MAIN"."VISIT" AS "f0"
  ON "d"."VENUE_ID" = "f0"."VENUE_ID"
GROUP BY "d"."VENUE_ID"`, though interesting case

Comment: It resembles [scenario I've encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477157/snowflake-left-join-lateral-unsupported-subquery-type-cannot-be-evaluated). Rewriting query is easy(and I guess most answer will focus on that). I am also curious what are EXACT rules that optimizer does that allow one query and forbid another.

Comment: This is a good solution to the problem I'm facing, but like I stated in the OP, I already have a way to retrieve the data I need. I'm looking for an explanation as to what's going on more than a solution to my specific requirements. Is this a bug in Snowflake I've found?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making this more complex than this needs to be.  Below should be all you need:

```
SELECT l.venue_id
  , count(distinct v.device_id)
FROM location l
LEFT JOIN visit v
 on l.venue_id = v.venue_id
GROUP BY l.venue_id
```

Comment: If the requirement is as originally expressed (and not a simplification of the real requirement) then you don't need even the location table; you can run the SELECT in the above query with just the visit table

Comment: You would need the location table to find scenarios where there would be 0 visits, they would not show up in a count from visit.

Comment: I agree - if that is part of the requirement, which it may be. Not clear to me if it is from the statement "I'm attempting to get the count of unique device ids by location"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a little cryptic, but what happens is this:

You are asking for **ONE** value and you need to guarantee that only **ONE** value is returned by your subquery. A distinct clause cannot guarantee that. In some databases that will work as long as the data returns one row, but the moment you get two rows then the database will throw an error.

Snowflake is strict on its subquery analysis. So you need to use a subquery that is guarantee to return always one value, for example select sum(..), select count(..)

Comment: The DISTINCT class in the query is wrapped within a COUNT(*).

Additionally, the first query in the question runs flawlessly, even with the DISTINCT present.

Comment: You are right. I tought I had figure it out, and it seems like that in most cases, but you are correct and I still do not have the right answer to understand why some subqueries are not supported

Comment: @GravlLift my current research (and this is just based on my tests) is that snowflake works with a query planner that uses a query rewrite method called subquery decorrelation. For this kind of query rewrites there are some subqueries that are not supported. For example: I had this query `UPDATE db1.tmetrics AS m SET m.OAGroup = (SELECT DISTINCT l.OAGroup FROM db1.group_mapping l WHERE l.agroup = m.agroup) WHERE OAGroup IS NULL AND AGroup IS NOT NULL` that was reporting an invalid subquery coz there was a NULL sensitive correlation. Adding a clause like  l.assignmentgroup is not null solved it