# Second greatests running value with SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I have a `table` such as:

| n | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 8 |

I can easily find the running max of this value:

```
SELECT *, max(value) over (order by n rows unbounded preceding) as mx
FROM table
```

| n | value | mx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 | 6 |
| 5 | 4 | 6 |
| 6 | 8 | 8 |

How can I get the second largest sliding number? so output is one such:

| n | value | second_mx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | 8 | 6 |

p.s:

```
SELECT *,nth_value(value,2) over (order by n rows unbounded preceding) as second_mx
FROM table
```

Do not work, because the `order by n` describes how to sort the nth.

Comment: Regardless of logic you want to achieve SQL and Snowflake have a very powerful tool for such cases called **[MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html)**

Comment: on n=2 previous rows are 1 and 4, so second max is actually 1. isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm providing a separate answer because this one is so different (and I may delete the other answer).  I am convinced this can be handled only with window functions.  And I think this offers a solution.

This starts with a bunch of explanation.  You can skip down for the query and link to db<>fiddle.

There are two cases where the second max is really simple:

- If the current value is the maximum value and it has appeared before, then it is the second max.
- If the current value is the maximum value and it has never appeared, then the previous maximum is the second max.

An additional simple case:

- If the value is less or equal to the previous second max, the second max does not change.

And finally, an important property of the second max:

- The second max is increasing.

So, the idea is to do the following:

1. Calculate the "easy" cases.
2. Assign the second in the "trivial" cases, when it doesn't change based on the easy cases.
3. Assign the current value in the rest.
4. Do a cumulative max of the second sum.

This results in:

```
select t.*, max(imputed_second_max) over (order by n) as second_max
from (select t.*,
             (case when sometimes_mx_2 is not null then sometimes_mx_2
                   when value <= max(sometimes_mx_2) over (order by n) then max(sometimes_mx_2) over (order by n)
                   else value
              end) as imputed_second_max
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when value = mx and nth_value > 1 then value
                         when value = mx and nth_value = 1 then lag(mx) over (order by n)
                    end) as sometimes_mx_2
            from (select t.*, max(value) over (order by n) as mx,
                         row_number() over (partition by value order by n) as nth_value
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
      ) t
order by n;
```

I found that I needed to augment the test cases to get better coverage.  I found that decreasing sequences are particularly tricky.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=916edb324bb887cbe3e145893e9011bd) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I'm giving this answer as the correct since it seams the cleanest one using only window functions.

Comment: Yes me too, i keep feeling that the problems is way easier than the solution

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to create an sorted cummulative array and take second element.

PostgreSQL(it could be easily extended if 3rd/4th/5th element is required by adjusting array index):

```
SELECT t.*,
     (sort(ARRAY_AGG(t.value) OVER(ORDER BY t.n), 'desc'))[2] AS sec_max
FROM t
ORDER BY n;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e980275b7c993c3a11da41d81b5ee01a)**

Ufnortunately Snowflake does not support cummulative ARRAY_AGG/STRING_AGG.

---

Below the version that build cummulative array using recursive cte, then array is sorted and second element is taken.

Data prep:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t
AS
SELECT 1 AS n, 1 AS value
UNION ALL SELECT 2,4
UNION ALL SELECT 3,4
UNION ALL SELECT 4,6
UNION ALL SELECT 5,4
UNION ALL SELECT 6,8;
```

Helper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort_desc(a array)
  RETURNS array
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
  return A.sort().reverse();
$$
;
```

Main query:

```
WITH src AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n) AS rn FROM t
),cte AS (
  SELECT *,  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(src.value) AS arr
  FROM src
  WHERE rn=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT src.*, ARRAY_APPEND(arr, src.value)
  FROM src
  JOIN cte
    ON cte.rn=src.rn-1
)
SELECT cte.n, cte.value, arr, array_sort_desc(arr), array_sort_desc(arr)[1] AS sec_max
FROM cte
ORDER BY n;
/*
+---+-------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+
| N | VALUE |                ARR                |       ARRAY_SORT_DESC(ARR)        | sec_max |
+---+-------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+
| 1 |     1 | [   1  ]                          | [   1  ]                          |         |
| 2 |     4 | [   1,   4  ]                     | [   4,   1  ]                     |       1 |
| 3 |     4 | [   1,   4,   4  ]                | [   4,   4,   1  ]                |       4 |
| 4 |     6 | [   1,   4,   4,   6  ]           | [   6,   4,   4,   1  ]           |       4 |
| 5 |     4 | [   1,   4,   4,   6,   4  ]      | [   6,   4,   4,   4,   1  ]      |       4 |
| 6 |     8 | [   1,   4,   4,   6,   4,   8  ] | [   8,   6,   4,   4,   4,   1  ] |       6 |
+---+-------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+
*/
```

Comment: if I undrestand this properly you are joingin the cte with itself to make a sort of a recursive join, is it so?

Comment: @DavidMabodo First in src I am making continous numbering then in cte part I have an anchor (rn=1) and recursive part that adds one next row at a time to array. Sort is applied once I have array ready (see column ARR that is not sorted)

Comment: I upvoted, but if you are going to use a recursive CTE, I don't think you need arrays.  Just keep the highest two values and swap them in as you go through the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's right, the recursive cte was a try to rewrite the array_agg logic one to one, which may be superfluous at this point :) On the other hand it is more generic, take the 3rd/4th element and so on. It was a nice puzzle.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda . . . I still feel like I am missing something that would greatly simplify the problem.

Comment: I've never used recursive cte's before, highly interesting. I yet assigned as correct another question that use only window functions

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.*, t2.value as second_mx
from t cross join lateral
     (select t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.n <= t.n
      order by t2.value desc
      offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only
     ) t2;
```

Actually, you can also express this as a correlated subquery.

That said, this will not have good performance on a non-smallish table.

Comment: Almost, **"Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated"** in this case :(
I had similar scenario long time ago:[Snowflake (LEFT JOIN) LATERAL: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477157/snowflake-left-join-lateral-unsupported-subquery-type-cannot-be-evaluated)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda . . . Bummer.  This is the most interesting question I've seen in a few days and -- barring a self-join -- I can think of several approaches but Snowflake doesn't support them.  I'm looking forward to an answer.

Comment: I would go with MATCH recognize as it is a pattern, or in last resort use recursive cte

Comment: The cleanest solution I have found, but it requires windowed ARRAY_AGG: [db<>fidde demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e980275b7c993c3a11da41d81b5ee01a)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda . . . I added another answer.  It is not "cleaner", but it only uses window functions.  It is very rare that I add multiple answers, but they are so different that it seemed warranted in this case.